# How do I import a DynamoDB table exported to S3 as a new table?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I don't want to use data pipeline because it is too cumbersome. I also have a relatively small table so it would be heavy handed to use data pipeline for it- I could run a script locally to do the import because it's so small.

I used the fully managed Export to S3 feature to export a table to a bucket (in a different account): https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DataExport.html

What are my options now for importing that to a new table in the other account?

If there isn't a managed feature for this, does AWS provide a canned script I can point at an S3 folder and give the name of the new table I want to create from it?

Comment: Where did you get to with this?
I've actually tried the data pipeline approach and, whilst it spins up some EC2 instances, it never gets beyond WAITING_FOR_RUNNER and never writes any logs to say what's going on.
I feel the UI (and UX) is very poor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Amazon DyanamoDB now supports importing data from S3 buckets to new DynamoDB tables from this [blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/amazon-dynamodb-can-now-import-amazon-s3-data-into-a-new-table/).

The steps for importing data from S3 buckets can be found in their [developer guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/S3DataImport.Requesting.html).

Answer (score 3):

As of 18 August 2022, this feature is [now built into DynamoDB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/S3DataImport.HowItWorks.html) and you need no other services or code.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to create a [AWS Data Pipeline](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/what-is-datapipeline.html) which already has recommended [template](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-template-exports3toddb.html) for importing DynamoDB data from S3:

[image]

This is the closest you can get to a "managed feature" where you select the S3 prefix and the DynamoDB table.

Answer (score 1):

Another AWS-blessed option is [a cross-account DynamoDB table replication](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/cross-account-replication-with-amazon-dynamodb/) that uses `Glue` in the target account to import the S3 extract and `Dynamo Streams` for ongoing replication.